# javascript: TypeError: document.getElementById("myTable") is null

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

i'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById("myTable") is null
```

on document.write(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].innerHTML);
It goes into a never ending loop.

Can someone tell me on what i'm doing wrong? Thank you.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function colorRows(){
count=document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
alert("count is:"+count);
            for (i=0;i<=count;i++){
                if (i%2===0){
                    document.write(document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable">

<tr>
    <th>emp_id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>vaani</td>
    <td>35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ramu</td>
    <td>37</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Iniyan</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Mickey</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
<form method="post" action="JavaScript:colorRows();">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works for me. I just copied and pasted your code here http://jsbin.com/onejuj/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you do `document.write` in the loop in the first time you clear dom and there is no more table element, and when you do `document.write` in the second time then `document.getElementById("myTable")` provides `null`. So browser stops the script provide the error.

Comment: Ok when i change document.write to alert it works fine. But what do u actually mean by "clear dom and there is no more table element"? I didn't know that document.write actually clears the dom.

Comment: Now, I tried changing it a little. Instead of getElementById("myTable"), i'm using getElementsByTagName("table"). I'm getting TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName("table").rows is undefined. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Ok, it works when i added [0], now it is getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows. Thanks Speransky Danil.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I run your code.
I put myTable to a new variable outside of for. It works fine. like that.

```
var myTableVar = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<=count;i++){
        alert("i = " + i);
        if (i%2===0){
            document.write(myTableVar.rows[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

Complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function colorRows(){
    count=document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
    alert("count is:" + count);
    var myTableVar = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<=count;i++){
        alert("i = " + i);
        if (i%2===0){
            document.write(myTableVar.rows[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable">

<tr>
    <th>emp_id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>vaani</td>
    <td>35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ramu</td>
    <td>37</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Iniyan</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Mickey</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
<form method="post" action="JavaScript:colorRows();">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function colorRows(){
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    count=table.rows.length;
    alert("count is:"+count);
    for (i=0;i<=count;i++){
        if (i%2===0){
            document.write(table.rows[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

Best to only access the table once anyway. document.write() clears the page because it calls document.open()