# document.getElementById returns null on an existing element after a document.write

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Here is the full error message:

```
mlg.html:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
  at ml (mlg.html:41)
  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (mlg.html:9)
```

I was making a mad libs game and I was just doing a quick test to find bugs and then I stumbled across this problem. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="ml()">Mad Libs!</button>
  <p id="display"></p>

  <script>
    function ml() {
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

      //mad lib 1
      if (x == 1 || 2) {
        document.write("test1");
      }
      //mad lib 2
      if (x == 3 || 4) {
        document.write("test2");
      }
      //mad lib 3
      if (x == 5 || 6) {
        document.write("test3");
      }
      //mad lib 4
      if (x == 7 || 8) {
        document.write("test4");
      }
      //mad lib 5
      if (x == 9 || 10) {
        document.write("test5");
      }
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue is that `document.write` overwrites the content of the entire page, thus there won’t be a `#display` element when that statement is reached. Also `x == 1||2` should be `x == 1 || x == 2`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12471249/4642212

Answer (score 1):

Do not use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), it’s [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/4642212). It overwrites the entire page with `test1`, or some similar string. Therefore, when `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = x;` is reached, no element with the ID of `display` will exist anymore and `document.getElementById("display")` will evaluate to `null`.

If you want to test your `if` statements, use [`console.log("test1");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) instead. Simply open the [browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (<kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) and you’ll see the messages there.

Speaking of your `if` statements: [they’re wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15901222/4642212). `if(test == 1 || 2)` will always evaluate to `true`, because `2` is truthy. That’s not what you want. What you want is `if(test == 1 || test == 2)`.

Alternatives: `if([1, 2].includes(test))`, `if([1, 2].indexOf(test) >= 0)` ([Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4728144/4642212)).